# Unable to set value in byte format to upload file to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

```
Employee Pojo Class:   


   @Entity
        @Table(name = "Employee")
        public class Employee implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "empid")
            private Integer empId;

            @Column(name = "empname")
            private String empName;

            @Column(name = "empaddress")
            private String empAddress;

            @Column(name = "salary")
            private Long salary;

            @Column(name = "empAge")
            private Integer empAge;
            // .......................................................
            @Column(name = "file_data")
            private byte data;

            public byte getData() {
                return data;
            }

            public void setData(byte data) {
                this.data = data;
            }

            // .......................................................

            public Integer getEmpId() {
                return empId;
            }

            public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
                this.empId = empId;
            }

            public String getEmpName() {
                return empName;
            }

            public void setEmpName(String empName) {
                this.empName = empName;
            }

            public String getEmpAddress() {
                return empAddress;
            }

            public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
                this.empAddress = empAddress;
            }

            public Long getSalary() {
                return salary;
            }

            public void setSalary(Long salary) {
                this.salary = salary;
            }

            public Integer getEmpAge() {
                return empAge;
            }

            public void setEmpAge(Integer empAge) {
                this.empAge = empAge;
            }

        }
```

This is my Jsp Page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add Employee Data</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/save.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="id">Employee ID:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" value="${employee.id}" readonly="true"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Employee Name:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" value="${employee.name}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="age">Employee Age:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="age" value="${employee.age}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="salary">Employee Salary:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="salary" value="${employee.salary}"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="address">Employee Address:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="address" value="${employee.address}"/></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="data">Upload File:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input type="file" path="data" value="${employee.data}"/></td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table> 
        </form:form>

  <c:if test="${!empty employees}">
        <h2>List Employees</h2>
    <table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Age</th>
            <th>Employee Salary</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
            <th>Employee Pic</th>
            <th>Actions on Row</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.age}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.address}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.address}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.data}"/></td>

                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${employee.id}">Edit</a> | <a href="delete.html?id=${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",
                prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",
                prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView SearchEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService
                .getEmployeebyName("Sunil Kumar")));

        // model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService
        // .getEmployeebyName(employeeBean.getName())));

        model.put("employees",
                prepareListofBean(employeeService.GetRowEmployeess1()));

        return new ModelAndView("SearchEmp", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(prepareModel(employeeBean));
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", null);
        model.put("employees",
                prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService
                .getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
        model.put("employees",
                prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
    }

    private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
        employee.setEmpAge(employeeBean.getAge());
        employee.setEmpName(employeeBean.getName());
        employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
        employee.setEmpId(employeeBean.getId());
        employeeBean.setId(null);
        return employee;
    }

    private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees) {
        List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
        if (employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()) {
            beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
            EmployeeBean bean = null;
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                bean = new EmployeeBean();
                bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
                bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
                bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
                bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
                bean.setData(employee.getData());
                beans.add(bean);
            }
        }
        return beans;
    }

    public EmployeeBean getEmployeenamesa(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
        bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
        bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
        bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
        bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
        bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
        bean.setData(employee.getData());
        return bean;

    }

    private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
        bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
        bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
        bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
        bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
        bean.setData(employee.getData());
        bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
        return bean;
    }

}
```

This is my Employee Bean class :

```
public class EmployeeBean {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Long salary;
    private String address;
    // ........................................................
    private byte data;

    public byte getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // .......................................................

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I am trying to add image in Data Base i have  field file_data why longblob but when i try to get file  from my local machine and try to upload image then i am getting null  Can not set byte field Employee.data to null value i don't know where am doing mistake while i have set all value if we remove data from file then i am able to  save data and get data from database i am having Problem  only with file part please suggest me where am doing wrong

Comment: To store an image you need byte array, not a single byte. Also, use [@Lob](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) annotation.

Comment: how to conver Byte array can u please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a byte for the File upload. You need to use the MultipartFile/byte[] for that.

Refer this link for more info .
Using Multipart : http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/975/spring-3-file-upload-example/

For JPA entity, you need to annotate with `@Lob` annotation

Comment: and my table is alredy file data in database table

Comment: @Lob enables to allow the value to be of larger size than varchar. You need to have the table column value as BLOB as well. I'm not sure what data is in DB.

Comment: alredy i have done that  
alter  TABLE employee
ADD file_data  longblob    this Query i have use and its work but i am facing to problem to inser image mean get image from jsp and set  it to contrller

Comment: any Solution please suggest me

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Did you follow the link? Modify controller and bean accordingly to support Multipart data. this should give you enough information

Comment: yes i follow But now it telling Property 'data' not found on type com.dineshonjava.bean.EmployeeBean  while i have alredy declaere private CommonsMultipartFile filedata;
 
 public CommonsMultipartFile getFiledata() {
  return filedata;
 }

 public void setFiledata(CommonsMultipartFile filedata) {
  this.filedata = filedata;
 }

Comment: Thanx its done now but image is not storing in databse